# How to create a new version of bundles through Addressables?

Tags: unity-game-engine, addressables

In client **version 1**, I have Addressable group with sprite resources, which is divided into separate bundles A, B, C via labels. [image: Addressable group example]
Now for client **version 2** I need to combine content from bundles A, B, C into one bundle D.

Therefore, I need players from older versions of the client to receive the data as it was (in separate bundles). But players of a newer version must receive data from the new package. This way, the new data will be placed in the CDN along with the old data.

According to this task I have several questions:

1. What do I need to do to get the data from the new package on the client? Is it enough to delete the old groups and create a new one, and then click the "Update previous build" button?
2. What to do with old bundles if the player has updated the client from version 1 to version 2? Do I need to remove them manually or can Addressables handle this on its own?